# android sipdroid RTP packet class hasMarker function always returns false.

Tags: android, network-programming, network-protocols, rtp, android-networking

I am using android SipDroid RTP packet class  in my VoIP android application.  I am fragmenting the  captured frames into small packets.  I have set seqno, timestamp and marker.
But when I see log  RTP packet marker  hasMarker function  always returns false . Even I set it to true it returns only false. So very difficult to reassemble complete frame so temporarly I reassemble packet based on packet size less than 1024  which is the last packet of respective timestamp.

any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use of Marker depends on the type of stream.  In most audio streams, Marker indicates a discontinuity in the stream (i.e. the first packet of a "spurt" of audio packets).  For video codecs, normally it means the last packet of a frame, though for most codecs this can also be inferred by a the timestamp changing in the next packet.  However, packet loss at a frame boundary can confuse that heuristic, so Marker can be useful.  (Some codecs (H.264) use internal explicit end-of-fragment packetization markers, making Marker mostly irrelevant.)

As to why it's disappearing - you need to debug your code and whatever libraries you're using, and probably also check tcpdumps/wireshark captures.